# Converting (cross) table into list view

Tags: r, crosstab

In the past I asked a question about how to [create cross tables from a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451394/how-to-make-a-cross-table-with-na-instead-of-x). I was recommended to use `xtabs` for this, which works great. Today, I have been searching to do the reverse and create a list view table from a cross table. I was hoping to find a reverse formula, but haven't been successful. I am confident that there is a predefined function for this, but can't figure out to find it.

I have the following table:

```
# load table     
crosstable <- structure(list(col1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), col4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), col6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), col7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), col8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8"), row.names = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", "row6", "row7", "row8", "row9"), class = "data.frame")

#display table
crosstable

     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
row1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
row2    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
row3    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
row4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
row5    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
row6    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
row7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
row8    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
row9    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
```

I would like to convert this into a table that shows something like the following:

```
row1 col1 0
row1 col2 0
row1 col3 0
row1 col4 1
row1 col5 0
...
```

Anybody able to point me in the direction of the function that will help to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like `data.frame(rows = rownames(crosstable), stack(crosstable))`?

Comment: How did you get this "crosstable" object to begin with? If you used `xtabs` you might just be able to do `data.frame(xtabs(blah blah blah))`

Comment: The crosstable object came from a matrix via `crosstable <- data.frame(matrix)`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I *thought* I had answered a question like this recently ;)

Comment: @AnandaMahto -- Yep, I had seen and liked your answer, so just clicked your name and added "stack" to the search bar to find it!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Very true! Just didn't make it to my search results with works like 'list view' and 'cross table'. Thus, the value of duplicate questions might be in making answers accessible via different search approaches. Thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: @Jochem -- Couldn't agree more. +1 for making your question so clear and reproducible.

Comment: @Jochem, agreed. That's why duplicated questions aren't necessarily deleted, but instead, hang around as "signposts" of sorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sticking with base R, you can use `stack`:

```
CTLong <- data.frame(rows = rownames(crosstable), stack(crosstable))
CTLong <- CTLong[order(CTLong$rows), ]
head(CTLong)
   rows values  ind
1  row1      0 col1
10 row1      0 col2
19 row1      0 col3
28 row1      1 col4
37 row1      0 col5
46 row1      0 col6
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reshape2::melt` to get:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(cbind(rownames(crosstable),crosstable))
# Using rownames(crosstable) as id variables
#    rownames(crosstable) variable value
# 1                  row1     col1     0
# 2                  row2     col1     0
# 3                  row3     col1     1
# 4                  row4     col1     0
# 5                  row5     col1     0
# 6                  row6     col1     0
# 7                  row7     col1     0
# ...
```